# Bootstrap modal: close current, open new

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked for a while, but I can't find a solution for this. I want the following:

- Open an URL inside a Bootstrap modal. I have this working off course. So the content is loaded dynamically.
- When an user pushes a button inside this modal, I want the current modal to hide, and immediately after that, I want a new modal to open with the new URL (which the user clicked on). This content of the 2nd modal is also loaded dynamically.
- If the user then closes that 2nd modal, the first modal must come back again.

Comment: Bootstrap 2 or 3? Can you set up a JS Fiddle of what you've got?

Comment: Bootstrap 2.3.1. I think I cant setup a JS Fiddle because of the dynamic content

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Without seeing specific code, it's difficult to give you a precise answer. However, from the Bootstrap docs, you can hide the modal like this:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

Then, show another modal once it's hidden:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  // Load up a new modal...
  $('#myModalNew').modal('show')
})
```

You're going to have to find a way to push the URL to the new modal window, but I'd assume that'd be trivial. Without seeing the code it's hard to give an example of that.

Comment: Strange enough, I got it working with Bootstrap 3. I think my code had a conflict with the Bootstrap Tooltips, and that is changed in version 3. Thanks

Comment: On bootstrap v3 event is 'hidden.bs.modal'

Comment: A solution with data-dismiss is much more elegant (atleast in 2015) and doesn't require any non-bootstrap javascript.

Comment: Thanks @coure2011

Comment: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#targetmodal" data-dismiss="modal"
This just works fine.

Answer (score 88):

I know this is a late answer, but it might be useful. 
Here's a proper and clean way to get this done, as @karima's mentioned above. You can actually fire two functions at once; `trigger` and `dismiss` the modal.

HTML Markup;

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<ANY data-toggle="modal" data-target="TARGET">...</ANY>

<div class="modal fade" id="SELECTOR" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-body"> ... </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">           <!-- ↓ -->  <!--      ↓      -->
      <ANY data-toggle="modal" data-target="TARGET-2" data-dismiss="modal">...</ANY>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/elmahdim/details/azVNbN/)**

Comment: No bueno because you'll notice that, after opening the first modal, scrolling the page works properly, but if you launch another modal from an existing modal the scroll then shifts to the background. This is a big problem if you have a modal that needs to be scrolled (e.g. if you're viewing on a mobile device).

Comment: I have a very similar problem but in angular. Do you know how to do the same thing you did here but in an angular controller and using the `templateUrl` and `windowClass` properties?

Comment: Thanks - works for me to. The main problem for me was that I missed `data-dismiss="modal"` on button

Comment: @Mahmoud , hey is there any way to avoid the vibrating kind of effect while loading the second modal from one? and how to avoid the extra scroll ?

Comment: That's a browser issue, in Google Chrome "shake" when change modal, close, or open. try `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` on html,body css

Comment: Excellent solution! It was exactly what I needed for navigating between modals.

Comment: the scrolling behavior is messed up since the "model-open" class disappears from <body> when opening the new modal, for whatever reason. Just make sure you have the class set
`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#YOURMODAL').on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
       $('body').addClass('modal-open');    
    });
});`

Comment: This doesn't work properly when using the fade option. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44391959/4367223

Answer (score 48):

It's not exactly the response but it's useful when you want to close the current modal and open a new modal.

In the html in the same button, you can ask to close the current modal with data-dismiss and open a new modal directly with data-target:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" 
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#modalRegistration" 
data-dismiss="modal">Register</button>
```

Comment: Problem with `data-dismiss="modal"` is, it will shift your content to left when you will close the second modal.

Comment: hmmmm. this method doesn't work for me.  The 1st one goes away but the 2nd never appears

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you had, Kevin, but it worked fine for me with Bootstrap 3. The first modal disappears and the other opens just fine :)

Comment: Worked beautifully for me! And very simple solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Simple and find as the best solution for showing and hiding modal.

Answer (score 12):

I use this method:

```
$(function() {
  return $(".modal").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
    var curModal;
    curModal = this;
    $(".modal").each(function() {
      if (this !== curModal) {
        $(this).modal("hide");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Problem with `data-dismiss="modal"` is it will shift your content to left

I am sharing what worked for me, problem statment was opening `pop1` from `pop2`

**JS CODE**

```
var showPopup2 = false;
$('#popup1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    if (showPopup2) {
        $('#popup2').modal('show');
        showPopup2 = false;
    }
});

$("#popup2").click(function() {
    $('#popup1').modal('hide');
    showPopup2 = true;
});
```

Comment: such a simple solution :)

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned above In the html in the same button, you can ask to close the current modal with data-dismiss and open a new modal directly with data-target:

`<button class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modalRegistration"  data-dismiss="modal">Register</button>`

But this will cause scroll-bar to disappear and you will notice that if the second modal was taller than the first one

So the solution is to add the following style in the modal inline style  :

`Style = "overflow-y : scroll ; "`

Comment: Exactly what was required to supplement the above-provided solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've also added styling to hide the scrollbar for the modal.

`scrollbar-width: none;
 -ms-overflow-style: none;
::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`

Answer (score 4):

By using the following code you can hide first modal and immediately open second modal, by using same strategy you can hide second modal and show the first one.

```
$("#buttonId").on("click", function(){
    $("#currentModalId").modal("hide");
    $("#currentModalId").on("hidden.bs.modal",function(){
    $("#newModalId").modal("show");
    });
});
```

Comment: Fixes the scroll issue as well

Answer (score 4):

You need to add following attribute to the link or button where you want add this functionality:

```
 data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" id="forgotPassword" data-target="#ModalForgotPassword"
```

A detaile blog: http://sforsuresh.in/bootstrap-modal-window-close-current-open-new-modal/

Comment: Works perfectly with bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 4):

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

it is used to close the existing opened  model. you can set it to the new model

Comment: I'm not usre this works on all versions of bootstrap. The dismiss modal in my case causes the modal to close and opens the new one, but it also removed the modal class from the body and then i am unable to scroll the modal down.

Answer (score 3):

### For Bootstrap v4

You can toggle between modals by having putting `data-dismiss="modal"` and `data-toggle="modal"` in the same HTML element. You'd also need the `data-target` attribute set to the modal you'd like to open.

Here's an example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal2" >
Open second modal
</button>
```

*Remember to set an id for each of the modals and have the data-target point to the one you'd like to open*

### For bootstrap v5

Same as v4 just using the attributes `data-bs-toggle` `data-bs-dismiss` and `data-bs-target`

Like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#Modal2" >
Open second modal
</button>
```

They've included an example of this [in the v5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals)

**NOTE:**

The two modals need to be independent of each other, not nested in one another, in order for this to work.
So if you're using an MVC framework, say for example ASP.NET MVC, and have the first modal as its own partial view, you can't have the second modal in that view. You'll need to put the second modal in the parent view.

Answer (score 2):

With BootStrap 3, you can try this:-

```
var visible_modal = jQuery('.modal.in').attr('id'); // modalID or undefined
if (visible_modal) { // modal is active
    jQuery('#' + visible_modal).modal('hide'); // close modal
}
```

Tested to work with: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals (click on "Launch Demo Modal" first).

Comment: I don't think you need the `.attr` bit, do you? Wouldn't this work just as well? `var visible_modal = jQuery('.modal.in'); if (visible_modal) { visible_modal.modal('hide'); }`.

Answer (score 2):

I have exact same problem, and my solution is only if modal dialog have [role="dialog"] attribute :

```
/*
* Find and Close current "display:block" dialog,
* if another data-toggle=modal is clicked
*/
jQuery(document).on('click','[data-toggle*=modal]',function(){
  jQuery('[role*=dialog]').each(function(){
    switch(jQuery(this).css('display')){
      case('block'):{jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('id')).modal('hide'); break;}
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/7/

I tried this and it works the first time I open the modal but not subsequent times.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue as @Gravity Grave whereby scrolling doesn't work if you use

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="TARGET-2"
```

in conjunction with

```
data-dismiss="modal"
```

The scroll doesn't work correctly and reverts to scrolling the page rather than the modal.  This is due to data-dismiss removing the modal-open class from the  tag.

My solution in the end was to set the html of the inner component on the modal and use css to fade the text in/out.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, writing this here in case someone in the future stumbles upon this and has issues with **multiple** modals that have to have **scrolling** as well (I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7)

What I did is have a button like this inside my first modal:

```
<div id="FirstId" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#YourModalId_2">Open modal</div>
```

It will hide the first and then display the second, and in the second modal I would have a close button that would look like this:

```
<div id="SecondId" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#YourModalId_1">Close</div>
```

So this will close the second modal and open up the first one and to make **scrolling** work I added to my .css file this line:

```
.modal {
overflow: auto !important;
}
```

**PS:** Just a side note, you have to have these modals separately, the minor modal can not be nested in the first one as you hide the first one

So here's the full example based on the bootstrap modal example:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Add lorem ipsum here
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
          Open second modal
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This code, close modal opened, open the new modal but inmediatly, new modal is closed.

```
$(nameClose).modal('hide');
$(nameOpen).modal('show');
```

My solution for open new modal after close other is:

```
function swapModals(nameClose,nameOpen) {
    $(nameClose).modal('hide');
    $(nameClose).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        console.log('Fired when hide event has finished!');
        $(nameOpen).modal('show');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just close all open modals before opening a new one

```
$('.modal').modal('hide'); // close all open modals
$('#login').modal('show'); // open a modal named #login
```

Answer (score 1):

Using click function:

```
$('.btn-editUser').on('click', function(){
    $('#viewUser').modal('hide'); // hides modal with id viewUser 
    $('#editUser').modal('show'); // display modal with id editUser
});
```

Heads up:

Make sure that the one you want to show is an independent modal.

Answer (score 1):

**In first modal:**

replace modal dismiss link in footer with close link below.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#"  data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#second_model_id">Close</a>
</div>
```

**In second modal:**

Then second modal replace top div with below div tag.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="add text for disabled people here" aria-hidden="true" id="second_model_id">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    $('#model1').modal('hide');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#modal2').modal('show');
},400);
```

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted solution, since no listener will be bound forever to the close modal event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
    $('#modal_id_you_want_to_hid').modal('hide')
});

// same as above button id
$("#buttonid").click(function(){
$('#Modal_id_You_Want_to_Show').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})});
```

Comment: $("#buttonid").click(function(){

                    $('#modal_id_you_want_to_hid').modal('hide')

            });

       // same as above button id   
        $("#buttonid").click(function(){
                $('#Modal_id_You_Want_to_Show').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})})

Answer (score 0):

I use another way:

```
$('#showModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#easyModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the previously opened modal while opening the new modal then you must do it from javascript/jquery by first closing the current open modal and then give a 400ms timeout to allow it to close and then open the new modal like below code :

```
$('#currentModal').modal('hide');

setTimeout(function() {
       //your code to be executed after 200 msecond 
       $('#newModal').modal({
           backdrop: 'static'//to disable click close
   })
}, 400);//delay in miliseconds##1000=1second
```

If you try to do it with the `data-dismiss="modal"` then it will have the scroll issue as mentioned by @gravity and @kuldeep in comments.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers helped me since I wanted to achieve something which was exactly the same as mentioned in the question.

I have created a jQuery plugin for this purpose.

```
/*
 * Raj: This file is responsible to display the modals in a stacked fashion. Example:
 * 1. User displays modal A
 * 2. User now wants to display modal B -> This will not work by default if a modal is already displayed
 * 3. User dismisses modal B
 * 4. Modal A should now be displayed automatically -> This does not happen all by itself 
 * 
 * Trying to solve problem for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new
 * 
 */

var StackedModalNamespace = StackedModalNamespace || (function() {
    var _modalObjectsStack = [];
    return {
        modalStack: function() {
            return _modalObjectsStack;
        },
        currentTop: function() {
            var topModal = null;
            if (StackedModalNamespace.modalStack().length) {
                topModal = StackedModalNamespace.modalStack()[StackedModalNamespace.modalStack().length-1];
            }
            return topModal;
        }
    };
}());

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/13992290/260665 difference between $.fn.extend and $.extend
jQuery.fn.extend({
    // https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/
    showStackedModal: function() {
        var topModal = StackedModalNamespace.currentTop();
        StackedModalNamespace.modalStack().push(this);
        this.off('hidden.bs.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){   // Subscription to the hide event
            var currentTop = StackedModalNamespace.currentTop();
            if ($(this).is(currentTop)) {
                // 4. Unwinding - If user has dismissed the top most modal we need to remove it form the stack and display the now new top modal (which happens in point 3 below)
                StackedModalNamespace.modalStack().pop();
            }
            var newTop = StackedModalNamespace.currentTop();
            if (newTop) {
                // 3. Display the new top modal (since the existing modal would have been hidden by point 2 now)
                newTop.modal('show');
            }
        });
        if (topModal) {
            // 2. If some modal is displayed, lets hide it
            topModal.modal('hide');
        } else {
            // 1. If no modal is displayed, just display the modal
            this.modal('show');
        }
    },
});
```

Working Fiddle for reference, **JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gumdal/67hzgp5c/**

You just have to invoke with my new API "`showStackedModal()`" instead of just "`modal('show')`". The hide part can still be the same as before and the stacked approach of showing & hiding the modals are automatically taken care.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant solution for BootStrap 3.x. The same modal can be reused in this way.

```
$("#myModal").modal("hide");
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
   $("#myModal").html(data);
   $("#myModal").modal();
   // do something more...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use mdb use this code

```
    var visible_modal = $('.modal.show').attr('id'); // modalID or undefined
    if (visible_modal) { // modal is active
        $('#' + visible_modal).modal('hide'); // close modal
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Bootstrap modal: close current, open new</h1>
  <p class="text-muted">
  A proper and clean way to get this done without addtional Javascript/jQuery. The main purpose of this demo is was to answer this 
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new">question on stackoverflow</a>
  </p>
  <hr />

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-1">Launch Modal #1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info"    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-2">Launch Modal #2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-3">Launch Modal #3</button>

  <!-- [ Modal #1 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-1" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #1</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-3" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #3</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- [ Modal #2 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-2" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #2</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-1" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-3" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #3</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- [ Modal #3 ] -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo-3" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="icon-xs-o-md"></i></button>
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title caps"><strong>Demo Modal #3</strong></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Placeholder..." />
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Action</button></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-1" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demo-2" data-dismiss="modal">Close current, Launch Modal #2</button>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr />
  <h3 class="caps">Usage:</h3>
<pre class="prettyprint">&lt;!-- Button trigger modal --&gt;
&lt;ANY data-toggle="modal" data-target="TARGET"&gt;...&lt;/ANY&gt;

&lt;div class="modal fade" id="SELECTOR" tabindex="-1"&gt;
  &lt;div class="modal-dialog"&gt;
   &lt;div class="modal-content"&gt;
    &lt;div class="modal-body"&gt; ... &lt;/div&gt;
     &lt;div class="modal-footer"&gt;           &lt;!-- ↓ --&gt;  &lt;!--      ↓      --&gt;
      &lt;ANY data-toggle="modal" data-target="TARGET-2" data-dismiss="modal"&gt;...&lt;/ANY&gt;
     &lt;/div&gt;
   &lt;/div&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
</div> <!-- end .container -->

<hr />
<footer class="text-center"><a href="https://twitter.com/_elmahdim">@_elmahdim</a></footer>
<br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to this but I think I've found working solution.

Required -

jQuery

**All** modals with a closing/dismissal button having attributes set as follows -

```
<button type="button" class="btn close_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">Close</button>
```

Please see the class **close_modal** added to the button's classes

Now to close all existing modals, we'll call

```
$(".close_modal").trigger("click");
```

So, wherever you want to open a modal

*Just add the above code and your all open modals shall get closed.*

Then add your normal code to open the desired modal

```
$("#DesiredModal").modal();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide modal dialog box.

**Method 1:** using Bootstrap.

```
$('.close').click(); 
$("#MyModal .close").click();
$('#myModalAlert').modal('hide');
```

**Method 2:** using `stopPropagation()`.

```
$("a.close").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#modal").modal("hide");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Method 3:** after shown method invoke.

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
```

**Method 4:** Using CSS.

```
this.display='block'; //set block CSS
this.display='none'; //set none CSS after close dialog
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste this code and you can experiment with two modals. Second modal is open after closing the first  one:

```
<!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- The Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal2">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Second modal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myModal2').modal('show')
    })
</script>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me in a React / Next.Js component.
I didn't need the `data-bs-dismis="modal"` attribute. `data-bs-dismis="modal"` was actually just hiding modal and not routing to target, so I removed it. I hope this helps in any way. I suppose it's the same with regular html since it's literally the same thing.

```
<div className='container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center my-2'>
     <span className='py-3'>
         Don't have an Account,
         <a href='/retail-user/' data-target='/retail-user/'>Create One
         </a>
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, I went through all the answers but I couldn't find a **Comprehensive** solution.

Here's my break with a function which will **close all current modals and thereafter you can open your targeted modal** through regular **modal()** method.

Additionally, I have added an argument which will close all the open modals **except the chosen modal provided in function argument**

```
function Close_All_Open_Modal(except_modal='')
    {
        if(except_modal!=='')
        {
// This will provide you information about the Modals being closed
            console.log('Closing all Modals except '+except_modal);    
        }
        
// This will let you know if the <body> has "modal-open" class
        var BodyHasModalClass = $('body').hasClass('modal-open');

        var openModals = 0; // No of Modals Open

            console.log(BodyHasModalClass); // True if there is any open modal
            
// Function will execute only if there is a Modal Open

            if(BodyHasModalClass)
            {
// Loop through each element with "modal" class
                $(".modal").each(function()
                {
                    this_modal = $(this);
                    if(this_modal.hasClass("show"))
                    {
                        var ModalName = this_modal.attr("id");
                        
                        if(except_modal!=='' && except_modal!==ModalName)
                        {
                            console.log(ModalName+' is open');
                            openModals++;
                            this_modal.modal('hide');
                        }
                        else if(except_modal=='')
                        {
                            console.log(ModalName+' is open');
                            openModals++;
                            this_modal.modal('hide');
                        }
                    }
                });
                
                console.log('Closed '+openModals+' Open Modals');
            }
    }
```

Let me know your views.