# Modal With Another Modal Causes Scroll on Body

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/

Open the first modal. It opens fine. Removes the background scrollbar.

Open the modal from within that modal. It causes the scroll to go to the background.

I searched for other solutions and none of them seem to fix this. I tried everything on this page: [Bootstrap modal: close current, open new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new) among others.

Javascript:

```
// Only one of these modals should show at a time.
$('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
})
.on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Update: The first and second modal must also allow scrolling as can be seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/21/

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/19/

Comment: Same issue. Click the first modal. Then the second. Then close the second. The scroll is on the background.

Comment: .modal('handleUpdate')

Readjusts the modal's positioning to counter a scrollbar in case one should appear, which would make the modal jump to the left.

Only needed when the height of the modal changes while it is open.
```$('#myModal').modal('handleUpdate')```

Comment: If you're recommending .modal('handleUpdate'), please post a fiddle of what you mean because I've tried that numerous ways without success.

Comment: Actually, that wouldn't change anything. It's only purpose is to correct the padding. See bootstrap.js where it says ``Modal.prototype.adjustDialog = function```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate further on Hardik response, what essentially is happening is a hard-coded, inline declarations for the `.modal-open` class to the body element. However, the `.modal-open` class, also has a nested declaration for `.modal-open .modal` where it sets the `overflow-y` property for the modal to be "auto" -- hence why it is scrollable. To accomplish this, add `.css("overflow-y", "auto")` to the modal that will be opened. This is what it would look like based off your fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Only one of these modals should show at a time.
    $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
        $('body').css("overflow","hidden");
        $(this).css("overflow-y", "auto");
    })
    .on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // @todo reload the job
        $('#myModal')
            .modal('show')
            .css("overflow-y", "auto");
    });

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // @todo reload the job
        $('body').css("overflow","hidden");
    })
    .on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // @todo reload the job
        $('body').css("overflow","visible");
    });
});
```

Results viewable here: https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/22/

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/hardikjain/e6x4hq9h/20/

changes:

```
$('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('body').css("overflow","hidden");
})
.on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // @todo reload the job
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // @todo reload the job
$('body').css("overflow","hidden");
})
.on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // @todo reload the job
$('body').css("overflow","visible");
});
```

Comment: *So* close. The second modal doesn't allow scrolling. I updated the issue and I'll update the question to reflect that.

https://jsfiddle.net/e6x4hq9h/21/

Answer (score 0):

Just add style

```
.modal { overflow-y: auto !important; }
```

Fixes the scrolling issue