# modal-open class gets dropped when opening a modal from a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal link inside a modal. The idea is to close that modal when it's fired and open another modal. The problem is, the `modal-open` class gets dropped when doing this which then causes scrolling issues inside the modal. Is there any way around this?

The link inside the Modal 1 is

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="edit_item" data-row="1">Open Modal 2</a>
```

And the code:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".edit_item", function() {

        var id=$(this).attr("rel");
        var row=$(this).data("row");
        var params="action=viewItem&item_id="+id+"&tbl=viewRow&row="+row;

        $('.modal').modal('hide');

        // Needed to wipe the content due to the different IDs ..
        $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
        $(this).find('.modal-body').empty();
        });         

        // Opening Modal 2 here ..
        open_box_edit(params,row);
});
```

And the modal firing:

```
function open_box_edit(params,row_id)
  {                 
      var URL=ajax_url+"/?"+params;
      console.log(params);
      console.log(row_id);


        var modal = $('#modal_edit');
        modal
            .find('.modal-body')
            .load(URL, function (responseText, textStatus) {
                if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                     textStatus === 'notmodified') 
                {
                    modal.modal("show");
                }
        });  


}
```

How can I make sure that `modal-open` stays even after firing `$('.modal').modal('hide');`?

Comment: look at this i think it will help you - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new). You can see there the answer of @Mahmoud, look at his codepen example - [example](http://codepen.io/elmahdim/details/azVNbN/)

Comment: Do you want it to behave like a Wizard/Dialog? Can you reuse the same dialog modal without closing it?

Comment: don't inline your events man

Comment: @erani_246 Did that, unfortunately wasn't helpful :(

Comment: @TOAOGG It's a different action, but I guess I could re-use the same modal yes, just wiping the .modal-body content.

Comment: @user1996496 please add fiddle example with the problem

Comment: Yes this is what I was heading too. FadeOut the old content and FadeIn the new one?