# Bootstrap Modal Auto open Close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

```js
function modalFunction(hideModal, showModal) {
            console.log(hideModal);
            console.log(showModal);
            $(hideModal).modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal',function () {
         $(showModal).modal('show');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<body>
<button class="btn btnp-default"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</a></button>
<button class="btn btnp-default"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup">Signup</a></button>
 
  <div class="modal" id="login">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p><a href="#" onclick="modalFunction('#login', '#signup')">Signup</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal" id="signup">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <p><a href="#" onclick="modalFunction('#signup', '#login')">Login</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Problem is I need too hide recent open modal and show another modal but below given code I stuck in loop where modal show and hide continuously. No way to prevent or close modal. As you can see in demo no way to close modal.

Here situation is

- Modal Login have link -> Modal Signin
- Modal Signup have link -> Modal Login

Comment: Isn't this already answered? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new

Comment: I already follow that answer. Run my snippet myModal is is stuck in loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it differently (using custom HTML attributes):

```js
$('[data-close]').click(function() {
  var closeModal = $(this).attr('data-close');
  var openModal = $(this).attr('data-open');
  $(closeModal).modal('hide');
  $(openModal).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Login</a></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup">Signup</a></button>

  <div class="modal" id="login">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p><a href="#" data-close="#login" data-open="#signup">Signup</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal" id="signup">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <p><a href="#" data-close="#signup" data-open="#login">Login</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given below is modern way of doing it. You can refer [this link](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) for further details of the way of creating modal dynamically.

```js
function showModal(typeid) {

  var message = $('#type_' + typeid);

  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: typeid==1?"Login": "Sign Up.",
    message: $('#type_' + typeid),
    buttons: [{
      label: typeid!=1?"Login": "Sign Up.",
      action: function(dialog) {
        dialog.close();
        showModal(typeid==1?2:1);
      }
    }],
    onhide: function() {
      $('#hidden-div').append(message);
    }
  });
}


function showModal1() {

  var message = $('#common_div');

  BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Login',
    message: $('#common_div'),
    onhide: function() {
      $('#hidden-div').append(message);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.setDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>



<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal(1)">login</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal(2)">Signup</button>
<br>
<br>Or you can do it in a better way
<br>
<br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal1()">login</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showModal1()">Signup</button>

<div id="hidden-div" style="display : none">
  <!-- Login div -->
  <div id="type_1" class="setDiv">
    This is login div.
  </div>

  <!-- Login div -->
  <div id="type_2" class="setDiv">
    This is signup div.
  </div>

  <div id="common_div" class="setDiv" data-title="Sign Up">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Signup</a>
      </li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Login</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div id="type_1" class="setDiv" data-title="Login">
          This is login div.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div id="type_2" class="setDiv" data-title="Login">
          This is login div.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```