# Multiple modals, work but do not close

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I would like to ask for assistance. So I have multiple modals linked to different buttons. They open fine and display correctly, but do not close at all unless the page is refreshed.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header">Hard Drive Format</li>
<li class="grey">£10</li>
<li>Format Hard Drive</li>
<li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
<li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
<li class="grey"><button 
onclick="document.getElementById('Modal1').style.display='block'">Sign 
Up</button></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header">Hardware Repairs</li>
<li class="grey">£50 and up</li>
<li>Format Hard Drive</li>
<li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
<li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
<li class="grey"><button 
onclick="document.getElementById('Modal2').style.display='block'">Sign 
Up</button></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
<ul class="price">
<li class="header">Hard Drive Format</li>
<li class="grey">£10</li>
<li>Format Hard Drive</li>
<li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
<li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
<li class="grey"><button 
onclick="document.getElementById('Modal3').style.display='block'">Sign 
Up</button></li>
</ul>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal1" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>1</p>
</div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal2" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>2</p>
</div>

</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal3" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>3</p>
</div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal1');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal2');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('Modal3');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>
```

And here is the CSS

```
/* Create three columns of equal width */
.columns {
float: left;
width: 33.3%;
padding: 8px;
}

/* Style the list */
.price {
list-style-type: none;
border: 1px solid #eee;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Add shadows on hover */
.price:hover {
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

/* Pricing header */
.price .header {
background-color: #111;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
}

/* List items */
.price li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

/* Grey list item */
.price .grey {
background-color: #eee;
font-size: 20px;
}

/* The "Sign Up" button */
.button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
}

/* Change the width of the three columns to 100% 
(to stack horizontally on small screens) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.columns {
    width: 100%;
 }
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `data-dismiss="modal"` on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal: close current, open new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253972/bootstrap-modal-close-current-open-new)

Comment: hi. are you using bootstrap framework ?

Answer (score 0):

If using bootstrap, you **don't** need to do this

```
.style.display='block'
```

**This defeats the whole purpose of you using a framework** in the first place. The `bootstrap`**(framework) already handles this for you**. All you need to do is give appropriate attributes to your elements so bootstrap recognizes them and does the task.

In your case, to make a modal work. All you need is the `data-toggle="modal"` and `data-target="#Modal1"` attributes **to the trigger element**(your button). These tells the framework to open a modal by the id `Modal1` on click of this element.

```
<li class="grey">
  <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1">Sign Up</button>
</li>
```

Then to close the modal, you need to give the `data-dismiss="modal"` on your **"x" span element**(you don't need the `class="close"` in this case).

```
<span data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
```

Alternatively, you could also use javascript to close the modal like so(you don't need the `data-dismiss="modal"` in this case)

```
$(".close").on('click', function() {
    $('#Modal1').modal('hide');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Hard Drive Format</li>
    <li class="grey">£10</li>
    <li>Format Hard Drive</li>
    <li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
    <li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
    <li class="grey">
      <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1">Sign Up</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="Modal1" class="modal" data-dismiss="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY this code

HTML

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Hard Drive Format</li>
    <li class="grey">£10</li>
    <li>Format Hard Drive</li>
    <li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
    <li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
    <li class="grey"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1">Sign 
Up</button></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Hardware Repairs</li>
    <li class="grey">£50 and up</li>
    <li>Format Hard Drive</li>
    <li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
    <li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
    <li class="grey"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal2">Sign Up</button></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="columns">
  <ul class="price">
    <li class="header">Hard Drive Format</li>
    <li class="grey">£10</li>
    <li>Format Hard Drive</li>
    <li>Removes ALL Files From Drive</li>
    <li>Fresh Install Windows</li>
    <li class="grey"><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal3">Sign Up</button></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal1" class="modal fade">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal2" class="modal fade">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="Modal3" class="modal fade">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</span>
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Create three columns of equal width */
.columns {
float: left;
width: 33.3%;
padding: 8px;
}

/* Style the list */
.price {
list-style-type: none;
border: 1px solid #eee;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
transition: 0.3s;
}

/* Add shadows on hover */
.price:hover {
box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2)
}

/* Pricing header */
.price .header {
background-color: #111;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
}

/* List items */
.price li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

/* Grey list item */
.price .grey {
background-color: #eee;
font-size: 20px;
}

/* The "Sign Up" button */
.button {
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 10px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 18px;
}

/* Change the width of the three columns to 100% 
(to stack horizontally on small screens) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.columns {
    width: 100%;
 }
}


/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

remove your JS File and give a try

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```